# Vtk renders another windows apart from the qvtkwidget

Tags: qt, render, vtk

I have a little problem that i think it's easy so get a solution, but i've come to the point of trying everything and still not working. I'm sure it something simple, so i'm asking help as i can't figure it out on my own.

I have a qvtkwidget on the centralwidget and it has no problem.

the problem is that every time i run the program it rends another box apart from the interface.

here's the part of my code that matters for this issue.

```
// Create renderer
  ren= vtkRenderer::New();
    ren->AddActor(outlineActor);
    ren->SetBackground(0.1,0.1,0.3);

// Drawing some X,Y,Z axes
  axes= vtkCubeAxesActor2D::New();
    //more stuff
    ren->AddViewProp(axes);
    ren->ResetCamera();

// Create a window for the renderer
  renWin= vtkRenderWindow::New();
    renWin->AddRenderer(ren);

// Set an user interface interactor for the render window
  iren= vtkRenderWindowInteractor::New();
    iren->SetRenderWindow(renWin);

  style = vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera::New();
    iren->SetInteractorStyle(style);

// Create a inicial camera view
vtkCamera *inicam= ren->GetActiveCamera();
  inicam->Zoom(1);
  inicam->SetViewUp(0, 0, 0);
  inicam->Azimuth(45);
  ren->ResetCameraClippingRange();

// Start the initialization and rendering
    renWin->Render();

// Assign the rendering window to the qvtkwidget
  ui->qvtkWidget->SetRenderWindow(renWin);
```

if someone as any idea about this i would appreciate.

Comment: I used to have this (years ago) as well with Qt, vtk on windows. I don't remember the exact fix but it may have had to do with the ordering of creation of the vtk objects. Does this happen if you comment out renWin->Render();

Comment: I just checked and I do have renWin->Render(); after qvtkWidget->SetRenderWindow in my code.

Comment: @drescherjm   
Hi, I put it after and then it only rends outside the interface

Comment: If you do not find a solution I will try to find an example in http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx#Qt that is similar enough to your code. I believe my code would be too complicated of an example.

Comment: @drescherjm but now i can't have an interactor because its code is `iren->SetRenderWindow(renWin);` and I don't have renWin, it should be  `iren->SetRenderWindow(ui->qvtkWidget->GetRenderWindow());` but it does not work.

Comment: I got it to work `iren = ui->qvtkWidget->GetInteractor();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after seeing the example i got it to work.

```
  ui->qvtkWidget->GetRenderWindow()->AddRenderer(ren);
```

Answer (score 1):

QVTKWidget already has an interactor. So use that one instead:

```
    auto interactorStyle = vtkSmartPointer<TestInteractorStyle>::New();

    QVTKInteractor* interactor = widget->GetInteractor();

    interactor->SetInteractorStyle(interactorStyle);
```